# How to start intent inside tab

Tags: android

I have a Tab Layout with four tabs. Navigation betweeen them works fine, but every tab is actually an activity menu with options. So inside every tab the user has a couple of options, and from there it starts an intent to another activity. And in doing so, tab bar is lost. Is there no way to put this two navigation schemes together, as in iOS?

Comment: is it necessary to start a new activity? wouldn't be enough to switch to another view within the tab, using for instance a `ViewFlipper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) provides exactly what i need. It works with a TabHost and provides a different navitation stack for each tab.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not: there is currently no easy way to basically host multiple task stacks within a single task. Would be nice though.

If you REALLY want to simulate it, you COULD make a global tab state (maybe off your Application object) and then put a tab bar in every activity that would configure itself off the global tab state. So when you "switch tabs" it would add a new Activity to the task but the tab bar would select the proper tab, and when you go back it would update the tab state before `destroy()`ing itself and then when it returns the right tab state would show. Might be moderately messy, but definitely possible.

If you do I'd love to see the code :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up making a tabbar-like xml and i include it in the bottom of every layout. Now also every activity extends from a common activity that implements button's behavior. It might not be very elegant, but for what i needed to do it fits just fine.

Comment: Turns out there is a solution as i show in my answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Nice: didn't know that you could nest them that way. Just saw a similar thing after you mentioned it at http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity